# Dynamically assign character limits within textareas based on CSS classes

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, debugging

I'm trying to create a bit of javascript that will insert text limits without having to reference each textarea individually, but utilize a class in case there is a situation where a textarea must be omitted. My debuggers aren't behaving, visual studio can't track the intellisence, and jsfiddle doesn't report an error. I'm a bit stuck with how to debug this. I don't really care if it uses jquery or not. I have a working version of code that only utilizes css ids instead of classes.

```js
$('.txtFeedback').html("characters remaining");
try {
  $(document).ready(function() {
    var textareas = document.getElementsByClassName("txtLimit");
    var feedbacks = document.getElementsByClassName("txtFeedback");
    var n = 0;
    for (var i = 0; i < textareas.length; i++) {
      var thisElem = textareas[i];
      var countX = textareas[i].style.marginLeft;
      $("#" + thisElem.id).keyup(function() {
        var text_length = $("#" + thisElem.id).val().length; //char count
        var text_remaining = $("#" + thisElem.id).maxLength - text_length;
        if (countX < thisElem.maxLength) {
          $("#" + feedbacks[n].id).css({
            marginLeft: '+=50pt'
          });
          countX += 50;
        }
        $("#" + feedbacks[n].id).html(text_length + '/' + text_max);
      });
      n++;
    }
  });
} catch (err) {
  document.getElementById("errors").innerHTML = err.message;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<textarea id="textarea" class="txtLimit" rows="8" cols="30" maxlength="99" style="z-index:1;"></textarea>
<div id="textarea_feedback" class="txtFeedback" style="z-index:2; margin-top:-18pt; margin-left:50pt"></div>
<div id="errors" width=100 height=3 00/>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you need to store the feedback element into a variable before you can try to get its id. I updated your snippet to do that. Also, I found that the `text_max` variable wasn't defined, so I arbitrarily defined that to be 300.

FYI, you can use the developer console (press F12) in JSFiddle to see errors.

EDIT: Based on the comments, I've updated `text_max` to be `thisElem.maxLength`.

```js
$('.txtFeedback').html("characters remaining");
try {
  $(document).ready(function() {
    var textareas = document.getElementsByClassName("txtLimit");
    var feedbacks = document.getElementsByClassName("txtFeedback");
    for (var i = 0; i < textareas.length; i++) {
      var thisElem = textareas[i];
      var text_max = thisElem.maxLength;
      var feedback = feedbacks[i];
      var countX = textareas[i].style.marginLeft;
      
      $("#" + thisElem.id).keyup(function() {
        var text_length = $("#" + thisElem.id).val().length; //char count
        var text_remaining = $("#" + thisElem.id).maxLength - text_length;
        if (countX < thisElem.maxLength) {
          $("#" + feedback.id).css({
            marginLeft: '+=50pt'
          });
          countX += 50;
        }
        $("#" + feedback.id).html(text_length + '/' + text_max);
      });
    }
  });
} catch (err) {
  document.getElementById("errors").innerHTML = err.message;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<textarea id="textarea" class="txtLimit" rows="8" cols="30" maxlength="99" style="z-index:1;"></textarea>
<div id="textarea_feedback" class="txtFeedback" style="z-index:2; margin-top:-18pt; margin-left:50pt"></div>
<div id="errors" width=100 height=3 00/>
```

Comment: just changed text_max to thisElem.maxLength; Good catch, I hadn't updated that from my last working attempt. Still trying to master the F12 debugger in browsers, I'll look for a video later when I get a chance. Thanks!